# How to handle embedded " (x86)" in PATH with parameter expansion

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping

Given a PATH of `C:\local\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\foo\bin;`

How do I escape or otherwise handle the embedded `(x86)` when using [parameter expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)?

Here's what I have now (ultimate aim is to extend the path to a known location if the specified .exe's are not currently in PATH):

```
for %%g in (touch.exe rsync.exe) do (
  if "%%~dp$PATH:g" =="" set PATH=%PATH%;%~dp0\bin
  )
```

and the current result (and with PATH being unchanged of course):

```
\foo\bin\ was unexpected at this time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a cmd line program that you can run to get a help screen etc, then this is one option: it will add the folder to the path if the file can't be found.

```
name.exe /? >nul 2>&1 
if %errorlevel% equ 9009 set path=%path%;c:\files\bin
```

Comment: thanks for the alternate approach. I hadn't considered anything like that. Is '9009' a reliable number or just an example? I thought programs define their own exit codes (meaning for one I might need 9001 and another 1008, etc.)

Comment: This errorlevel is set by Windows (it is reliable) if the command cannot be found, so is the same for any command that doesn't exist or can't be found.